# Ionic - text input on Android 10+ not echoed

Tags: android, ionic-framework, textinput

I've been experiencing the most peculiar error with my Ionic app when running it on Android 10.

The attached gif should pretty much sum up what's the problem but what I can tell is that it's working properly on Android devices with a version lower than ten.

Basically speaking, none of the actual input is echoed to the screen unless I hit some visual divider (ie space). It applies to virtually every text input in the app but the login screen should be enough to get the idea.

**Text input on android 10 device:**

[image]

And to provide some code as well, this would be the affected login code snippet.

```
<ion-content no-bounce id="login-content">
  <img
    src="assets/logo/datenpool-logo-blue.svg"
    alt="datenpool-logo"
    title="datenpool-logo"
    id="datenpool-logo"
  />
  <form [formGroup]="loginForm">
    <div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
      <ion-input
        placeholder="{{ 'authentication.login.form.username' | translate }}"
        type="text"
        formControlName="username"
        [formControl]="loginForm.controls['username']"
        required
      ></ion-input>
      <ion-input
        placeholder="{{ 'authentication.login.form.password' | translate }}"
        type="password"
        formControlName="password"
        [formControl]="loginForm.controls['password']"
        required
      ></ion-input>
      <mat-error *ngIf="isInvalid">
        {{ error }}
      </mat-error>
      <button
        (click)="login()"
        type="submit"
        [disabled]="!loginForm.valid"
        class="button"
      >
        {{ 'authentication.login.form.button' | translate }}
      </button>
    </div>
  </form>
  <div fxLayoutAlign="center center">
    <button (click)="forgotPassword()" class="forgotpw">
      {{ 'authentication.login.forgot-password' | translate }}
    </button>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

Personally I doubt that the code is faulty but rather that it's something to do with Android and its predictive text feature.
At any rate, I hope somebody can point me towards the right direction; thanks in advance, guys.

Comment: Same problem happened with me in ios, for me i created new project and copy paste the files without any change and it worked, it was error in the creation of the project from npm, it got crashed upon creation at a point maybe. Try to do the same.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to find the reason behind the problem.

What I didn't mention is that the project is using Capacitor. And due to that there exists a `capacitor.config.json`. And in that JSON file there's a dedicated android block with the following properties:

```
"android": {
    "backgroundColor": "#ffffffff",
    "allowMixedContent": true,
    "captureInput": false,
    "webContentsDebuggingEnabled": true
  },
```

What happened was that `captureInput` was set to true. And what **[captureInput](https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/basics/configuring-your-app/#common-configuration)** does is to replace the standard Android keyboard with a simpler one thus enabling devs to use key capture events more easily.

What it apparently also does is to render text input on Android 10 virtually useless.